# How can I add a related record whilst on its parents edit page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table of venues and offers. Each venue can have have many offers.

I would like to be able to add the offers to the venues from the venues edit page. So far I have this (code below) but its giving a "NoMethodError in Venues#edit, undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" error.

**venues edit page**
(the div id="tabs-3" is a container in an accordion)

```
   <div id="tabs-3">
      <%= form_for [@venue, @offer] do |f| %>

        <h2 class="venue_show_orange">Offers</h2>

         <%= f.fields_for :offers do |offer| %>
           <div class="add_offer">
             <%= offer.text_field :title %><br>
           </div>

           <div class="button"><%= submit_tag %></div>
         <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

**offers controller**

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @offer = Offer.new
  end

  def create
    @offer = @venue.offers.create!(params[:offer])
    @offer.venue = @venue
    if @offer.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Offer added'
      redirect_to offers_path
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
    @offer.attributes = params[:offer]
    if @offer.save!
      flash[:notice] = 'Offer updated successfully'
      redirect_to offers_path(@offer)
    end
  end
end
```

**venues controller**
(nothing offer related in here - is this where I'm going wrong?)

```
class VenuesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :only => [:update, :delete, :create] 
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    @venue = Venue.new
    5.times { @venue.venuephotos.build }
  end

  def create
    @venue = Venue.new params[:venue]
    if @venue.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Venue added'
      redirect_to venues_path
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
    5.times { @venue.venuephotos.build }
  end

  def update
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
    @venue.attributes = params[:venue]
    if @venue.save!
      flash[:notice] = 'Venue updated successfully'
     redirect_to :back
    end
  end
end
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks very much!

**edit**

**venues edit page**

```
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <%= form_for @venue do |f| %>
        <div class="edit_venue_details">
          <h2 class="venue_show_orange">Offers</h2>

          <%= render :partial => 'offers/offer', :collection => @venue.offers %>

          <div class="clearall"></div>

          <h2 class="edit_venue_sub_header">Add a new offer</h2>
          <%= f.fields_for :offers do |offer| %>
            <% if offer.object.new_record? %>
              <p class="edit_venue">title: <br>
              <%= offer.text_field :title, :class => "edit_venue_input" %></p>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>

        <button class="submit_button" type="submit"> Save changes</button>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

**whats being displayed**

[image]

however if I add a new offer, that will display correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
<%= f.fields_for :offers, @venue.offers.build do |offer| %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks:

1) Replace:

```
<%= form_for [@venue, @offer] do |f| %>
```

with:

```
 <%= form_for @venue do |f| %>
```

Because `offers` data will be updated through the related `venue`, only one controller action will handle the form.

2) If you want to add some unexisting `offers` in this form, you shoud instantiate them the way you did with `venuephotos`

3) Show your `Venue` model. You should have at least:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :offers
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it works only now when I try to add the offer partials to the venue edit page (just above where the add new offer text_fields are) using: <%= render :partial => 'offers/offer', :collection => @venue.offers %> I get 2 extra offer partials showing the current venues edit path. I added 2.times { @venue.offers.build } into the venue controller how can I stop this? Any added offers show up fine just with these 2 extra partials showing.

Comment: I don't understand what you write here. Could you edit your question?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add the updated view page to my question and I'll try add a picture of whats being displayed. I now only get 1 partial showing the current venues edit path as I changed the venue controller to read: 1.times { @venue.offers.build }.